# LibreOffice for Linux: How to open paths in LO with single click

Tags: linux, file-management, libreoffice-writer

I'm using LibreOffice Version: 6.0.4.2 under Linux OS in German language. I also use Plasma, where I set to open paths with a single click. I want to open paths in file handling in LibreOffice modules (Writer, Draw, Calc...) with one (single) click also.

How can I achieve this? If not possible to explain for German menu and settings in LO, then at least English settings would be ok.

Thank you in advance.

-Auguste

Comment: Also posted at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/156727/linux-how-to-open-path-in-lo-with-single-click/.